# How to set content type using Azure Java azure-storage-blob SDK

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

My code looks like:

```
    try {
        MultipartFile file = uploadFileInfo.getUploadFile();
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
        BlobProperties props = blockBlobClient.getProperties();
        blockBlobClient.upload(inputStream, file.getBytes().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Unable to upload blob!", e);
        return baseResp;
    }
```

However the file contentType is application/octet-stream, and I need to set it to "image/jpg". How can I do this with the Java SDK?

Answer (score 2):

To upload a blob and set it's content type, please use the following method: [`BlockBlobClient.uploadWithResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_specialized_BlockBlobClient_uploadWithResponse_java_io_InputStream_long_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobHttpHeaders_java_util_Map_java_lang_String_java_lang_String__com_azure_storage_blob_models_AccessTier_byte___com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobRequestConditions_java_time_Duration_com_azure_core_util_Context_). Here's the sample code (taken from the same link):

```
BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders()
     .setContentType("image/jpg");
 
 Map<String, String> metadata = Collections.singletonMap("metadata", "value");
 
 byte[] md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 
 BlobRequestConditions requestConditions = new BlobRequestConditions();
 Context context = new Context("key", "value");
 client.uploadWithResponse(data, length, headers, metadata, AccessTier.HOT, md5,
         requestConditions, timeout, context);
```

Comment: "image/jpg" does not work, you need to use "image/jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

The `upload` method does not provide this option, you need to use the `uploadWithResponse` method, which allows you to specify this and many other parameters. Here's an example:

```
ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions = new ParallelTransferOptions();
BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
Map<String, String> metadata = Collections.singletonMap("metadata", "value");
BlobRequestConditions requestConditions = new BlobRequestConditions();
Context context = new Context("key", "value");
Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(60);

blobClient.uploadWithResponse(inputStream, size, parallelTransferOptions, headers, metadata, AccessTier.HOT, requestConditions, timeout, context);
```